# How can I pass a Google maps Marker into an intent from my Android MapsActivity?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, google-maps-markers

If this is possible, will the Marker if updated within the Intent be translated directly to my maps app ui and displayed immediately upon update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass an instance of an object through an intent. You could try serializing the object and then deserializing it in the new activity but that would be a new instance of the object and, if modified, won't update the original one.